# Terraformation vs. terraformage

Tags: choix-de-mot

Is there any difference between the meaning of [*terraformation*](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=terraformation&oldid=35093963) and [*terraformage*](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=terraformage&oldid=35123410)?

I [see](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=terraform) that both are used to translate "terraforming":

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the French version of the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/terraformation), "Terraformation" is the science behind the terraforming. "Terraformage" is more like a completed process of terraforming, a final result.

As a proof, we can see at the end of "Terraformage", coming from the verb "Terraformer",  the word "-age" is often used to speak about the result of an action.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with what has been said before, but I think there is no correct answer *yet*.

They are new words, both not in dictionaries (*) yet so you should be careful if you use them in a paper. They're both attempts of translating "terraforming" and I'd say they mean the same thing, only time will tell if they're synonyms, variants or if one of them is just wrong.

(*) Wiktionnary is a community-based dictionary. It's very good in most cases but be careful with neologisms.